# Why i am unable to create a sequence in R?

Tags: r

Here is my code to genrate sequence of numbers. The sequence starts from 3 and stops at the sqaure root of a number input by user.

```
num = as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter a number :"))
mysqrt = as.integer(sqrt(num))
myseq = seq(from = 3,to = mysqrt, by = 2)
```

The error I get is ->

```
Error in seq.default(from = 3, to = mysqrt, by = 2) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

If i run ->

```
seq(3,as.integer(sqrt(25)), by = 2)
```

it works fine as expected.

If i run ->

```
num = 25
seq(3,as.integer(sqrt(num)), by = 2)
```

it gives the above error.

Comment: Did you tried with `num <- 25`?

Comment: I can only reproduce the error your getting if `to` is less than 9. If you enter a number whose square root is less than the value in `from` (3 in this case), then you'll get an error. So the code will work as long as the value entered is 9 or greater. When `to` is less than `from`, `by` has to be negative to prevent the error you're getting. You can test for this and change `by` accordingly, or you can require the user to enter a number that is greater than or equal to 9.

Comment: It would be more natural to write a function than use `readline`, e.g. `sqrt_seq <- function(to, from = 3, by = 2){seq(from, sqrt(to), by = by)}; sqrt_seq(100)` And you don't need `as.integer` (or more explicitly `floor`), as that's how `seq` behaves anyway.